# How to Configure Hibernate Property File Config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, frameworks

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
        StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                loadProperties("hibernate.properties").build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Course.class)
                .getMetadataBuilder().build();

        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Its not working. I  also want to configure hibernate using property file (well known to xml configuration).

Comment: You can find a reference here https://docs.atlassian.com/hibernate2/2.1.8/reference/session-configuration.html

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-5-java-configuration-example